# Creating lists and sub items in R markdown not working any longer?

Tags: r, markdown

I'm following the following cheat sheet:

https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf

And trying to make some lists using the following code (copy pasted from the cheat sheet)

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Test"
date: "7 August 2017"
output: html_document # or pdf_document
---

* unordered list
* item 2
 + sub-item 1
 + sub-item 2

1. ordered list
2. item 2
 + sub-item 1
 + sub-item 2
```

But the results are not the same as in the cheat sheet, the circles are not the same and the sub items do not get indented.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

For everyone that has problems showing simple list, markdown need an `Empty line` before a list.

`This will not work
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3`

The output will look something like this.
This will not work
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3

To fix this;
`INSERT EMPTY LINE HERE, BEFORE LIST.`
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3

should output like this

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 19):

Try using `tab` or double `tab` separation instead of `spacebar` for sub items

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Test"
date: "7 August 2017"
output: html_document # or pdf_document
---

* unordered list
* item 2
    + sub-item 1
    + sub-item 2

1. ordered list
2. item 2
    + sub-item 1
    + sub-item 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when you have tab width set to 2 spaces the ordered list sub-items do not nest appropriately, but an unordered list will. This is problem is solved when using a double tab (or four spaces) to inset sub-items.

For example:

```
2 space tab works for unordered lists

* unordered list
* item 2
  + sub-item 1
  + sub-item 2

<br>

2 space tab doesn't work for Ordered list

1. ordered list
2. item 2
  + sub-item 1
  + sub-item 2 

<br>


Double tab (or 4 spaces) solves the problem

1. ordered list
2. item 2
    + sub-item 1
    + sub-item 2
```

[image: example Rmarkdown output]